# vim on ubuntu desktop is very laggy and slow, but vim.tiny is fine

Tags: vim

Recently I changed my work environment from Windows to Ubuntu Desktop, and I met a strange problem I never met before.

I found vim on the gnome-terminal of the Ubuntu desktop quite slow and laggy, and I found if change back to vim.tiny, it is just fine.

I have used vim quite frequently on Linux server(often by ssh), windows, macos, and never found vim laggy.

The feeling of laggy and slowness is very hard to articulate, H, J, K, L moving the cursor is fine, but I (to insert) and ESC has an obvious delay.

Comment: Start with https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/205, I suppose

Comment: Have found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307148/vim-scrolling-slowly `set ttyfast` and `set lazyredraw` in `~/.vimrc` would be some candidates...

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213597/how-to-see-which-plugins-are-making-vim-slow/12216578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update:

Out of desperate, I thought why not compile vim from the source.
So I did, and vim works like a charm.

```
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
cd vim/src
make
make install
```

Sadly, after enough searching and trying. the normal vim just can't be as smooth as vim.tiny.

I guess the problem is specifically associated with the vim on gnome-terminal on Ubuntu Desktop.

Until now, I hava no choice but stick with vim.tiny.

The normal vim on ubuntu desktop is laggy, but if you ssh to the Ubuntu desktop machine, vim just works fine.

So I highly suspect the problem is related with GUI desktop or something.

Comment: Mine is not (and has not been) laggy on Ubuntu 20.04.2 with gnome-terminal 3.36.2

Answer (score 1):

In case you also want to checkout the startup time for vim, you can use the `--startuptime` to create a file showing how much time each
plugin (and many other processes) is adding to the start up time:

```
vim --startuptime profile_vim_startup.vim
```

will make a file called 'profile_vim_startup.vim'

As an example, The end of my file shows that the YouCompleteMe plugin takes
about 100ms to load:

```
times in msec
 clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
 clock   elapsed:              other lines
   .        .           .
   .        .           .
   .        .           .
g62.216  000.010: start termcap
062.238  000.022: clearing screen
062.614  000.376: opening buffers
062.648  000.034: BufEnter autocommands
062.650  000.002: editing files in windows
064.780  000.578  000.578: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/youcompleteme.vim
157.396  094.168: VimEnter autocommands
157.401  000.005: before starting main loop
157.892  000.491: first screen update
157.893  000.001: --- VIM STARTED ---
```

The full file (100 lines) for mine is this:

```
times in msec
 clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
 clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.003  000.003: --- VIM STARTING ---
000.059  000.056: Allocated generic buffers
000.086  000.027: locale set
000.090  000.004: GUI prepared
000.092  000.002: clipboard setup
000.094  000.002: window checked
000.322  000.228: inits 1
000.337  000.015: parsing arguments
000.337  000.000: expanding arguments
000.350  000.013: shell init
003.271  002.921: xsmp init
003.442  000.171: Termcap init
003.474  000.032: inits 2
003.599  000.125: init highlight
003.908  000.220  000.220: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/debian.vim
004.496  000.479  000.479: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim
004.566  000.586  000.107: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/synload.vim
008.489  003.893  003.893: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim
008.516  004.572  000.093: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syntax.vim
008.529  004.905  000.113: sourcing $VIM/vimrc
008.583  000.007  000.007: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim
008.637  000.024  000.024: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/ftplugin.vim
008.689  000.020  000.020: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/indent.vim
008.879  000.130  000.130: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/autoload/vundle.vim
009.042  000.103  000.103: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/autoload/vundle/config.vim
012.043  000.006  000.006: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim
012.228  000.005  000.005: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/ftplugin.vim
012.404  000.005  000.005: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/indent.vim
013.428  000.227  000.227: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/pack/dist/opt/matchit/plugin/matchit.vim
013.476  000.516  000.289: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/macros/matchit.vim
013.588  001.657  001.125: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/vim-sensible/plugin/sensible.vim
018.137  000.168  000.168: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/nosyntax.vim
018.439  000.089  000.089: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim
018.595  000.355  000.266: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/synload.vim
018.614  000.671  000.148: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syntax.vim
022.585  000.116  000.116: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim
023.185  000.110  000.110: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim
023.529  000.107  000.107: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim
025.434  002.721  002.504: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/vim-colorschemes/colors/seoul256.vim
025.446  003.198  000.361: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/vim-colorschemes/colors/seoul256-light.vim
026.373  017.826  012.016: sourcing $HOME/.vimrc
026.376  000.046: sourcing vimrc file(s)
026.746  000.172  000.172: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/vim-commentary/plugin/commentary.vim
026.810  000.009  000.009: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/vim-sensible/plugin/sensible.vim
027.212  000.365  000.365: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/vim-surround/plugin/surround.vim
027.502  000.236  000.236: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/ReplaceWithRegister/plugin/ReplaceWithRegister.vim
027.716  000.169  000.169: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/vim-indent-object/plugin/indent-object.vim
027.947  000.054  000.054: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips/map_keys.vim
028.015  000.249  000.195: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/plugin/UltiSnips.vim
028.225  000.163  000.163: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/vim-tmux-navigator/plugin/tmux_navigator.vim
028.883  000.615  000.615: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/vim-indentwise/plugin/indentwise.vim
029.048  000.117  000.117: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/vim-slime/plugin/slime.vim
029.594  000.506  000.506: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/fzf/plugin/fzf.vim
030.358  000.710  000.710: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/fzf.vim/plugin/fzf.vim
030.636  000.228  000.228: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/traces.vim/plugin/traces.vim
030.831  000.060  000.060: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/vim-mundo/autoload/mundo/util.vim
031.019  000.338  000.278: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/vim-mundo/plugin/mundo.vim
033.256  002.191  002.191: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/vim-fugitive/plugin/fugitive.vim
055.155  009.211  009.211: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/vim-unimpaired/plugin/unimpaired.vim
055.683  000.445  000.445: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/plugin/youcompleteme.vim
055.949  000.200  000.200: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/vim-tmux-focus-events/plugin/tmux_focus_events.vim
056.059  000.045  000.045: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/Tabmerge/plugin/Tabmerge.vim
056.300  000.202  000.202: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/targets.vim/plugin/targets.vim
056.509  000.049  000.049: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
056.691  000.170  000.170: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/gzip.vim
056.858  000.155  000.155: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/logiPat.vim
056.893  000.021  000.021: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/manpager.vim
057.035  000.131  000.131: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/matchparen.vim
057.473  000.424  000.424: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
057.522  000.027  000.027: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/rrhelper.vim
057.558  000.020  000.020: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/spellfile.vim
057.692  000.120  000.120: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
057.797  000.085  000.085: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/tohtml.vim
057.937  000.126  000.126: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
058.106  000.146  000.146: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
058.179  000.015  000.015: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim82/pack/dist/opt/matchit/plugin/matchit.vim
058.235  000.011  000.011: sourcing /home/mattb/.fzf/plugin/fzf.vim
058.242  014.195: loading plugins
058.293  000.051: loading packages
058.550  000.103  000.103: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/after/plugin/UltiSnips_after.vim
058.671  000.275: loading after plugins
058.685  000.014: inits 3
059.101  000.416: reading viminfo
062.199  003.098: setup clipboard
062.206  000.007: setting raw mode
g62.216  000.010: start termcap
062.238  000.022: clearing screen
062.614  000.376: opening buffers
062.648  000.034: BufEnter autocommands
062.650  000.002: editing files in windows
064.780  000.578  000.578: sourcing /home/mattb/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/youcompleteme.vim
157.396  094.168: VimEnter autocommands
157.401  000.005: before starting main loop
157.892  000.491: first screen update
157.893  000.001: --- VIM STARTED ---
```